# Location.country_code - Fancybox, now popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I used to have a fancybox display a message to users based on the country they were visiting from like so:

```html
<script>
  jQuery.ajax({ 
    url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
    type: 'POST', 
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(location) {
      // If the visitor is browsing from United Kingdom.
      if (location.country_code === 'GB') {
        // Tell him about U.S. store.
        jQuery.fancybox.open(jQuery('#messageGB'));
      }
    }
  });
</script>
<div id="messageGB">
  <p>You are visiting our U.S. store. </p>
</div>
```

I was having some problems with fancybox placing cookies so now I am using a jquery pop up which works fine on its own, but it doesn't work if I try to do the country based call... any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

```html
  // If the visitor is browsing from United Kingdom.
  if (location.country_code === 'GB') {
    // Tell him about U.S. store.
    $('#popup_messageGB').popup({
      setcookie: true,
      cookie_timeout: 0
    }
  }
});
</script>
<div id="popup_messageGB">
  <p>You are visiting our U.S. store. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Cross Domain Ajax the Easy Way

Cross domain ajax requests need to be done in a specific way, which the web service needs to support.  And the geo location service that you are using does support "jsonp" cross domain requests ... so you're in luck.

Note the callback parameter added to the query string. Your code is missing the callback, which is probably why it's not working.

> http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=onGeoLocation

The jQuery documentation explains how to make a jsonp call [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

And your jQuery code would looks something like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(data) {
     // your popup here
});
```

Yet, for something simple like this one doesn't really need jQuery.  You only need retrieve the visitor's location once.  That can be done by including the web service URL in a normal script tag.  And after it loads it will call your function with the returned data.

**Update: In response to comment**

@RobRob - Just copy the code below, add your popup code, and you're done.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(location) {
         // insert your popup code here
          alert( location.country_name );
       });  
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The example below demonstrates both methods of doing the jsonp call.

**Run The Code Snippet to Display Your Country**

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="getLocation()">jQuery.getJSON</button>
<h2 id="country_name"></h2>
JSON:
<xmp id="stdout" style="border:1px gray solid; background-color:aliceblue;"></xmp>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  // Method 1: plain Javascript jsonp callback
  
  function onGeoLocation( data ) {
       document.getElementById('stdout').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data,null,'  ');
    
       document.getElementById('country_name').innerHTML = 'Country: ' + data.country_name;
    
       // add your popup here
    
  };
  

  // Method 2: Using jQuery 
  
  function getLocation() {
    $.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(data) {

         alert( 'jQuery.getJSON\n' + JSON.stringify(data, null, '  '));
         // your popup here
            
    });  
      
  }
  
</script>
<!-- This script tag required for method 1 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=onGeoLocation"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Robert very much appreciated, sadly this is a bit out of my knowledge base. I was hoping more for of a fix along the lines of what I already have :/

Comment: @RobRob - See the update.  This is close to what you have as $.getJSON() is just shorthand for the more complex $.ajax() method you are already using.  The key to making it work is the that the URL must have a "callback" parameter.